# How does this Runescape character look like a bush?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I was just chilling at the GE, gearing up for a slayer task, when I noticed a talking bush also just chilling. How did this person turn themselves into a bush? I didn't think there's a jewelry item for it like the ring of coins or third age... is it some sort of graphical glitch then?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the effect of equipping the [Ring of Nature](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Ring_of_nature). The Ring of Nature can be obtained through completing Elite Clue Scrolls.

Comment: I swear as long as I've played this game I'm still finding new stuff that I didn't even know existed. Thanks for the quick answer!